# Refresh a Bound DataGrid on a MouseDoubleClick event

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, datagrid, observablecollection

On a ListBoxItem, I have a MouseDoubleClick event like this:

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="84" Margin="97,599,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="88">
    <ListBoxItem MouseDoubleClick="Ajout_MouseDoubleClick" Name="Ajouts" Content="Ajouts"/>

The event is as follow:

private void Ajout_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DbSet<Resultat> res = cnn.Resultat;
    var add = from a in res
              where a.Remarque.Equals("Ajoute")
              select new { a.Groupe_D_alerte, a.LibelléTOTApres, a.LibelléTOTAvant, a.NomChamp, a.NomTable, a.Remarque, a.SiModifie, a.TOTMPMRQ };
    cnn.SaveChanges();
    DonneesBrutes.Items.Refresh();
}
```

What it is supposed to do is realise a LinQ request into the DbSet called Resultat. It's a simple filter in one column, "Remarque" in this case. Once this filter is applied in the DbSet, I need to refresh the DataGrid binding target of the DbSet "Remarque"

the DataGrid looks like this:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DonneesBrutes" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=.ResultatCollection}" Margin="10,65,0,0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="PMRQ" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=.TOTMPMRQ}" Header="PMRQ"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="LibellePMRQ" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=.LibelléTOTApres}" Header="Libellé PMRQ"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Ligne" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=.Remarque}" Header="Ligne"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="OTM" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=.TOTMPMRQ}" Header="OTM"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="TOTM" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=.SiModifie}" Header="TOTM"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="LibelleTOTM" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=.LibelléTOTApres}" Header="Libellé OTM"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="GA" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=.Groupe_D_alerte}" Header="GA"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Discipline" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=.NomTable}" Header="Discipline"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="DisciplineSubstituee" Width="120" Binding="{Binding Path=.NomChamp}" Header="Discipline Substituée"></DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

When I double click, the script execute itself, but it happen nothing, I don't see the filter applied in the DataGrid (To bind datas from DbSet to DataGrid, I use an ObservableCollection)

Answer (score 1):

WPF is *not* WinForms. There is no `DataGrid.Refresh` method. We do *not* refresh our UI controls. In WPF, we use data binding and implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface to propagate property changes between the UI and our code behind or view models. Therefore, when we make a change to the data object or objects that are data bound to UI controls, the update is immediate. Therefore, we have no need to 'refresh' anything.

Please see the [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN for more information on this subject.